# Angular custom filter to campare two numbers in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Angular project.
We have a array called data with:

```
$scope.data= [
    {_id: '1', rev: 1-bar}, 
    {_id: '2', rev: 2-bar},
    {_id: '3', rev: 3-bar},
    {_id: '4', rev: 4-bar},
    {_id: '5', rev: 1-bar},
    {_id: '5', rev: 2-bar},
    {_id: '5', rev: 3-bar}
];
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="items in data | unique: '_id'">

 {{items._id}}


</div>
```

We are using a Angular-filter called unique to only show one of the items with _id but it cant sort out the rev. This means that when a revision is made it is not shown before the angular-page is reloaded. 
We need to sort out the data so only the _id with the highest rev is shown.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: just see doc for [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: The result we are looking for is like;  "_id:'5', rev: '3'". Because rev:3 is the highest of the rev's where id:5.

Comment: `unique` is your own filter? or a 3rd-party? can you provide code for it?

Comment: 3rd-party filter by https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#unique. It works nice but only half way.

Comment: It may just be me but im struggling to understand the question. So you want to group them by `_id` and only show the one from each group with the highest `rev`?

Comment: @ste2425 yes something like that. Meaning that we group those with the same _id and after that we only show the one with the highest rev. Hope you understand.

Comment: may be you can add one more ng-repeat inside (since items could be many) on items and show only max rev. among that

Comment: you can do it in js code, also you can see `https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

Comment: @Grundy I am not sure how groupBy would work. Can you explain?

Comment: @SimonMühl, in comment above i suggets `groupby` not `orderby` :-) if you mean first comment - i thought you just want sort result _after_ unique

Comment: @grundy My bad. Meant of course GroupBy ;)

Comment: see @teksan, answer :-) it almost what you need, just add https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#max

Comment: but better - once do it in js, so your `data` already would be uniqued and sorted, you in html you can just `<div ng-repeat="items in data" >`. Better because this filters executed on every digest loop

Answer (score 0):

Group By -id and sort by -rev in descending then select only first element.

```
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | groupBy: '_id'">   

         {{value|max: 'rev'}}

  </div>
```

Try this.

Comment: here you order by 'rev' after unique, but OP say that unique should get max `rev` from duplicates

Comment: also `unique` not grouping, so in your sample `items` not an array - it just object

Comment: This will as @Grundy states only give me one item with the first rev. I need the "last" rev to be shown

Comment: now, you write **elem[0]** _value.length_ times :-) OP need output max

Comment: nope :-) you not need in nested repeat :-) just something like `{{value | max:  'rev'}}`

Comment: thanks @Grundy for pointing in right directions :) . Simon it will be good if you could verify this.